# VSC wrong import dir when switching environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, anaconda, package

After I switch from my global interpreter to my Anaconda interpreter, Visual Studio Code still looks in the old directory for modules/packages when I use import. So when I switch to my Anaconda interpreter and import Numpy and subsequently use numpy.**file**, it refers to the version of Numpy in my global directory (rather than my Anaconda environment). This causes some imports to fail since some packages only exist in my Anaconda environment. I have been looking around a lot, but I can't find anything about how I can set VSC up to look at the right location when importing when I switch interpreters (i.e. switch environment rather than only switch interpreter).

VSC is the problem. When I do the above mentioned Numpy test in - for example - Jupyter Notebook started from Anaconda the import is set correctly. Can someone help me with setting up my VSC code to look at the correct directory when I select an interpreter?

Comment: First of all can you please validate that if you use your anaconda interpreter from the command line it actually imports the correct version of numpy ? And after that you can understand it's the vscode that creates the problem.

Comment: good question: I did check that and VSC is the problem. When I do the numpy test in for example a jupyter notebook started from Anaconda the import is set correctly. Added this to my question.

Comment: What is the vscode output when you run the file with the should be environment ? For instance mine is: `/usr/bin/python /home/username/works/example.py`. It should point to the correct location.

Comment: Thanks for helping. When I use the . __file__ it always refers to the location where the packages are belonging to the global python environment, regardless of which interpreter belonging to whatever environment I select. It never refers to the location of the packages beloning to the environment  to which the selected interpreter belongs (unless I select the global interpreter). So it only points to the correct location when I use my global interpreter, which is exactly my problem. I want it to switch when I switch interpreters. In short; it only changes interpreter, not env or package loc

Comment: I switch interpreters using Ctrl + Shift + P (or sometimes using the bottom left button), I subsequently import packages from the script itself. I presume the setup has something to do with the VSC settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using conda the easiest way to solve this is to launch VS Code from your activated conda environment.

1. Launch the Anaconda Prompt (Windows-only)
2. Activate the conda environment
3. Launch VS Code w/ `code`
4. Make sure to select the conda environment from within VS Code

That way VS Code inherits the environment from the conda environment and thus sets things up so imports in a conda environment work.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is it. How simple could it be! Though I was hoping there was a way to set up VSC to automatically do this when I switch interpreter.

Comment: Unfortunately conda doesn't provide us with a way to do the activation reliably for you (we have asked, so we are waiting to see if they ever provide an appropriate mechanism to us). We are hoping to make this more obvious via https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10668 (please feel free to  the issue to help us prioritize it).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch a shell with your corresponding anaconda interpreter, that's a different thing and running the script with the corresponding interpreter is another.

Vscode obeys the given interpreter when you run your file from the command palette, `Ctrl + Shift + P` and then selecting `Python: Run Python File in Terminal`. It evaluates this command in the console like:

`/dir1/dir2/dir3/path_to_your_anaconda_python.py app.py`

Just selecting the interpreter in vscode and trying to launch a terminal where you run `import numpy` won't work as you expect.